# how to send verification email to specific users only in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-tenants for multi-tenancy,All things are good with allauth package.
But the problem is:
I've signup form for **"subscribers"** they must receive an **email confirmation** and a custom signup form for every "subscribers" to enable them to **create users** under their subdomains, But the **"created users"** must receive an email with an **initial password** not **confirmation email**.
Really I tried many things to perform this mission but with no solution and I searched in many threads here but unfortunately useless,
I tried to override
`def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):`,
`def send_confirmation_mail(self, request, emailconfirmation, signup):` and
`class CustomConfirmEmailView(ConfirmEmailView):`.

I knew that I've missed something but I don't know what is it. If I send a confirmation email to **"subscribers"**, **"created users"** affected , And if I change settings to prevent sending confirmation email the **"subscribers"** affected

Also I've a custom login form in adapter.py file to enable users to login with username.

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView): 
    template_name = 'account/subdomain/login.html'
```

**This is my settings**

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'apps.authentication.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.CustomUser'


ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'login': 'apps.authentication.forms.CustomLoginForm',
    'signup': 'apps.authentication.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
}

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'account_login' # created users must redirect to their subdomain login page not public login page 


ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True  # If True it will logout the user immediately

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True          #* It's not working for some reason but I don't know why, we have Handled from forms.py 

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True

#* to solve subdomain users login for now
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional' # to send mail for subscribers not to created users but it doesn't fix the issue

ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = None # To prevent login on verification for created users but the subscribers affected    

# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = '/auth/email/success/'  

# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/'                 

ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True  # try to solve the issue

ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True

ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 10 

#* This setting to enable us to access sign up view when authenticated
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = False 
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = 'account_login'
```

**Update: Some of my tries to solve the issue**

I tried to solve this issue by making redirect to the
`return redirect('account_email_verification_sent')`
But I failed.

**This is the custom signup view in adapter.py**

```
class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
    '''
        We override this class to 
        Make Signup form for Customers == Subscribers users from dashboard
    '''
    print('working done .......')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # print('Enter form valid')
        self.user = form.save(self.request)
        # mobile = self.user.mobile_number
        self.user.first_login = False

        client = Client.objects.create(
            schema_name=self.user.company_name,
            type=self.user.industry,
            name=self.user.company_name,
            description='any for now',
        )
        print('client is: ', client, self.user.industry)
        domain = Domain.objects.create(
            domain=self.user.company_name + '.localhost',
            tenant=client,
            is_primary=True,
        )
        print('domain: ', domain)
        with schema_context(self.user.company_name):
            CustomUser.objects.create(
                password=self.user.password, username=self.user.username,
                first_name=self.user.first_name, last_name=self.user.last_name, 
                company_name=self.user.company_name , mobile_number=self.user.mobile_number,
                email=self.user.email, operating_countries=self.user.operating_countries, 
                hq_country=self.user.hq_country, operating_cities=self.user.operating_cities,
                shipments_per_month=self.user.shipments_per_month, address=self.user.address, 
                industry=self.user.industry, first_login=False
            )
            # domain = Domain.objects.prefetch_related('tenant').get(tenant__name=self.user.company_name)

        return redirect('account_email_verification_sent')
```

**And this is the signup view for "created users"**

```
def create_user(request):
    with schema_context(request.tenant.schema_name):
        url = request.get_host() #request.tenant.get_primary_domain()
        user_url = url + '/accounts/login/'
        # obj = Domain.objects.select_related('tenant').get(domain=url)
        
        print('url= ', url, 'obj= ',request.tenant.type)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SupplierCreationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                save_form = form.save(commit=False)
                save_form.industry = request.tenant.type
                save_form.operating_countries = ''
                save_form.operating_cities = ''
                save_form.hq_country = ''
                save_form.first_login = True
                save_form.save()
                
                from django.core.mail import send_mail
                send_mail(
                    subject='Action Required',
                    message='''
                        Congratulations, Your password is:''' + str(request.POST.get('password1')) + '''  ,
                        Go to this link (http://''' + url + '''%s'''  %reverse('account_login') + ''') to login
                    ''',
                    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    recipient_list=[save_form.email]
                )
                print('sending mail done ... ')
                return redirect('create_user')
        else:
            form = SupplierCreationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'account/create_user.html', context)
```

Any help. If I missed some code to elaborate the issue, please tell me to update my question,
Thanks

Comment: I fixed my issue and want to share my solution with the community, But stackoverflow block me to answer my question says:"we are no longer accepting answers from this account "... why all these restrictions it's so simple. I'm learning it's normal to make mistakes, In MSDN I can make mistakes and find developers to guide me to the right way. Really I miss MSDN community

Comment: Any ways, I still need to help anyone have the same problem(It's not a problem but it's a behavior) to make some users **signup with email verification** and other users created without send email verification, You have to override the SignupView() class as you can see in the above code and add this line `send_email_confirmation(self.request, self.user)` before return to a success URL.
Thanks stackoverflow